# Excel VBA PasteSpecial not pasting consistently

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have a report which is used to import data relating to jobplans and then creates graphs and stats based on the data. Calculations and graphs are based on tables and the tables are populated by VBA - user selects the file and then VBA checks it matches the expected file format and put everything in the right place.

**HOWEVER**, the pastespecial part of the code does not paste everything correctly. Specifically there are a number of columns with datevalues and when pasted some of them (not one column or particular rows but seemingly random cells) are not formatted as dates when pasted and therefore are not captured in formulas when I look for job within particular timeframes.

In the source file the all data is 100% saved as a datevalue (if I put a filter on the data, it is all grouped by year and can be expanded to month/day/time + if I use a test cell to do add 1 to the cells that the next date is shown). Once pasted into target sheet then some is still a datevalue but some appears to be text and showing as dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm but being missed from calculation. On these cells if I go onto them press F2 and then Enter then the cell changes to a datevalue (realigns to the right and then gets included in daterange formulas).

Here is the code:

```
Public Sub importdata()
Dim wb1, wb3 As Workbook
Dim ws1, ws3 As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long
Dim WOtable As ListObject
Dim searchcell As Range

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Dashboard")
Set WOtable = ws1.ListObjects("workorder")

WOfile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.CSV),*.CSV", Title:="Select Workorder Extract To Be Opened",MultiSelect:=False)
If WOfile = False Then Exit Sub
Set wb3 = Workbooks.Open(WOfile)
Set ws3 = wb3.Sheets(1)

ws3.Range("M:M, O:O, Q:Q").EntireColumn.Delete
   If ws3.Range("A1").Value = "jobnumber" And ws3.Range("B1").Value ="jobdesc" And etc etc Then
   lrow = ws3.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    ws3.Range("A2:O" & lrow).Copy
   WOtable.DataBodyRange(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Else: MsgBox ("File selected to import workorder information was not in expected format, please check the file and retry.")
End If

wb3.Close False

End Sub
```

I have tried to add the following line before copying to force it based on something I saw on google but to no avail:

```
ws3.Columns("E:K").NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS"
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: You could run text to columns with default parameters against the column/s in question to do the equivalent of F2/Enter for the entire column - This can be done programmatically.

Comment: Using Copy and Paste to move data around a workbook(s) is very messy and error prone as you using one singe clipboard (for the whole OS) to move information around. E.g. if you have multiple processes running and using the clipboard, you will have the situation where you paste another processes data in a place you were expecting something else. Have you tried rather copying the info into an array then writing that array back to the sheet you want the info? (It will also preserve the type and you won't have contention for the clipboard).

Comment: @765tgs ah I see, maybe that is causing an issue. I have not tried to do that nor have I done that before, if you know of any good resources where I can learn how to do that then I would greatly appreciate if you could share otherwise I will try and find something on google. Thanks

Comment: @Zerk thanks for the reply. 765tgs has suggested a different way of copying the data across might be a good way forward however if that does not work then I will look at fixing it after the paste using text to columns. would that work within a table?

Comment: @SMLBW Transferring via array as 765tgs suggests is preferable, though for other reasons such as in-memory data manipulation as opposed to on-sheet. Both methods work absolutely fine and I can confirm that the array method seems to maintain the date format from a quick test. I'll post an answer for you with an example approach. The text to columns approach can be done on a table but you iterate through the columns in a loop.

Comment: @Zerk okay great, thanks for your help. if transferring data via an array is the preferred solution in general then now seems like a good time for me to learn how to do it! appreciate your help and any further advice

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in comments, an example usage of pushing the data into a variant array and then pasting it to the destination. A few comments:

- Always state what type you want for each variable, comma separated variables on the same line don't all take the last type.
- Use with statements to keep code slightly cleaner and reduce the amount of references excel needs to resolve.
- As you didn't clear the contents of the table (merely overwrote them) I replicated this behaviour in the code as I assume it is intended.

Edited sub:

```
Public Sub importdata()
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb3 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
Dim WOtable As ListObject
Dim varTMP As Variant

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Dashboard")
Set WOtable = ws1.ListObjects("workorder")

WOfile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.CSV),*.CSV", Title:="Select Workorder Extract To Be Opened", MultiSelect:=False)
If WOfile = False Then Exit Sub
Set wb3 = Workbooks.Open(WOfile)
Set ws3 = wb3.Sheets(1)

With ws3
    .Range("M:M, O:O, Q:Q").EntireColumn.Delete
    If .Range("A1").Value = "jobnumber" And .Range("B1").Value ="jobdesc" And etc etc Then
        'load data into variant array
        varTMP = .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        'If you want to do any data manipulation on the array, do it here
        'Paste array
End With
        With WOtable.DataBodyRange
            Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(0 + UBound(varTMP, 1), 0 + UBound(varTMP, 2))) = varTMP
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox ("File selected to import workorder information was not in expected format, please check the file and retry.")
    End If

wb3.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! Couple of questions. Firstly, the table is already blank when I go to load this data - does that change what you suggest given your third bullet point? Secondly, do I need to adap the (1,1).CurrentRegion line so that the correct number of rows and columns are pulled into the array or does the currentregion bit makes some assumptions?

Comment: 1) The table being blank is fine. 2) CurrentRegion(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) will select the entire dataset if there aren't any blank rows or columns partway through it (Well managed data shouldn't have these). If they are present and there is no way to remove them then specify your range using standard approaches.

Comment: thanks. there may have blank rows and columns (data that is pulled in may not be properly refined by other users when exporting data from separate jobplan software). do you think the line varTMP = .Cells(2, 1).offset(15,lrow-1) would work assuming there are 15 columns (this is fixed) and I insert the line lrow = ws3.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row beforehand? will be back at my PC and able to test tomorrow. thanks

Comment: If that is the case then xldown will face the same issue with blanks. Instead use lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).row and then define the array as follows: varTMP = range(.cells(2,1),.cells(lrow,15))

Comment: I have only just been able to test your suggestion and unfortunately copying the data via the array method has not resolved the issue. I have done some more testing and no matter which method I use, certain cells with datevalues in them copy as text rather than as a number. Do you happen to know anything else that might be causing this?

Comment: I think the problem is being caused by excel trying to format the dates in a different manner, switch the days and months and therefore the 1st Feb is switched to the 2nd Jan and any date where the day is 13-31 then it is not pasted properly